# Open File Dialogs - setting the InitialDirectory location?

Tags: c#, dialog

How can I set the initial directory of where an Open File Dialog appears? I'd like to change it to the images folder that sits in my /bin/Debug folder. I just can't get it to work.

```
opdPicture.Title = "Choose a Picture";
opdPicture.InitialDirectory = ""; //Don't know what to set this to.
```

Comment: What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: Well I'm not exactly sure how to approach it. I've tried "/bin/Debug/images" or just "/images." But the only examples I can find online are from "C:\\" which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Application.StartupPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath?view=net-5.0) will give you the directory the exe is in, so I imagine you want to use [Path.Combine](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=Path.Combine&x=0&y=0) to get the images directory relative to the startup path.

```
var imagePath = System.IO.Path.Combine( Application.StartupPath, "images" )

opdPicture.Title = "Choose a Picture";
opdPicture.InitialDirectory = imagePath ;
```